# How to reset jquery variable on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an `<a>` tag in my html structure in which there is a `<li>` tag inside it (as you can see in html code) and there is a `data-` attribute inside that `<li>` which i'm trying to pass an id with it.

There are several `<a>` tags in my page which every one opens individual bootstrap modal. As you can see every `<a>` tag has an individual id and also every modal has an individual referenced id too.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="taskItemSettingsModalLink{{ $task->id }}" href="#taskItemSettingsModal{{ $task->id }}" data-toggle="modal">
    <li class="tk-task-box" data-task-id="{{ $task->id }}" data-task="{{ $task }}" data-task-status="{{ $task->status }}" data-list-id="{{ $list->id }}">{{ $task->name }}</li>
</a>
```

**Note**: This HTML is written in laravel blade views; Though, these {{ ... }} tags belongs to blade.

In jquery i want to retrieve that data attribute on click and set it to a var named `taskId`.
My problem is, based on what i want to do, i need to reset this `taskId` value and empty it every time the `<a>` tag is clicked and the modal is shown. I've found no way doing this. However, now it's just adding `taskId` to previous one.

**What I've tried:**

- setting `taskId` to `null`:

```
$('a[id*=taskItemSettingsModalLink]').on('click', function () {
    taskId = null;
    var taskId = $(this).children('li').data('task-id');
    //...
});
```

- setting `taskId` value to empty:

```
$('a[id*=taskItemSettingsModalLink]').on('click', function () {
    taskId = val('');
    var taskId = $(this).children('li').data('task-id');
    //...
});
```

- setting `taskId` value to `undefined`:

```
$('a[id*=taskItemSettingsModalLink]').on('click', function () {
    taskId = undefined;
    var taskId = $(this).children('li').data('task-id');
    //...
});
```

- used `removeData()` method
- used `delete`:

```
delete taskId;
```

As mentioned above, I need to reset `taskId` on every click on `<a>` tags which it means on every modal show i need a fresh `taskId`.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
What i should do is setting `taskId` inside click event; because i'm retrieving `data-task-id` from that `li` inside `a` tag. So, I can define `taskId` variable just inside the event. And in my opinion, I can only empty it just the line i'm declaring variable...

Answer (score 0):

You can just set it so `undefined` or `null`. see the example given below.

```
let x = 10; //your variable
$('#demo').on('click' , function(){
    x = undefined // x = null
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I would really appreciate if you read my update on the question and send another reply if possible.

Comment: have to tried to log the value of variable using `console.log()` ? try once and post the output here.

Comment: I have tried ```console.log(taskId)```. It's working as expected; returns the related ```data-task-id``` which belongs to ```<a>``` tag clicked.  
But if i try to set the ```taskId``` to either of ```null```, ```undefined``` or empty it, the result is not what expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the second argument for `data`

```
$('a[id*=taskItemSettingsModalLink]').on('click', function () {
    var taskId = $(this).children('li').data('task-id');
    $(this).children('li').data('task-id', ''); // to reset it
});
```